# How to copy a mat over a bigger mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I want to copy an image on a mat that has the image of the camera, I could not achieve it yet. I understand that this can be achieved using copyTo (). Could someone help me do it? This is the last thing I try:

```
         cv::Mat image=cv::imread("./Sombrero.png",-1);             
         cv::Rect rect(20,20,image.cols,image.rows);
         cv::Mat subdst=mat(rect);
         image.copyTo(subdst);
```

Im trying to do that for Android in Qt Creator.

Comment: `Mat::copyTo` function checks if source and destination images are of the same size and type. If they're not then it reallocates the destination image.

Comment: Are you sure that `image` has the same format as `mat`? Are you sure you want that alpha channel?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to extract an ROI in this line: `cv::Mat subdst=mat(rect);`. What is `mat` and how do you intend to use it ?

Comment: the mat is a matrix where I have the image of the cell phone. What I want to do is that when the camera detects a face, draw an image on the face of the person.